# Custom content type selector in jslink?

Tags: content-type, jslink

I'm trying to customize the content type selector from a jslink file.

I tried the *standard* approach, but it does not trigger :

```
(function () {

    var customContentType = function (ctx) {
        return "it's working"
    };

    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};

    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "ContentType": {
            "EditForm": customContentType
        }
    };           
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

Also tried on `ContentTypeId`, but no more success.

Is there any way to customize Content Type selector ?

PS: I know I can hide the native drop down under the carpet and manually trigger event with

```
var oobCTSelector = document.querySelector("[id$='ContentTypeChoice']");
oobCTSelector.style.display = "none";
...
oobCTSelector.onchange();
```

but I thinks it's a bit hackish.

**[Edit]** One clue that let me think it's not even possible is that if I inspect the context object I get :

```
ctx.FieldControlModes

>Attachments: 2
> Author: 1
> Champ_x0020_CT_x0020_01: 2
> Created: 1
> Editor: 1
> Modified: 1
> Title: 2
```

There's no mention to content type field

Comment: Did you try `ContentTypeChoice`, just because...why not?  It might not work at all, anyway. If you look at the rendering templates (DefaultTemplates.aspx), most of the forms have a `ChangeContentType` template that is separate from the `ListFieldIterator` or `CSRListFieldIterator` template, so it's quite possible that the Content Type drop-down is rendered on the server and never goes through the CSR cycle.

Comment: Unsuprisingly, it does not work using ContentTypeChoice. Where do you find the defaulttemplates.aspx ? (or did you mean ascx ?)

Comment: Ah yes, my bad, it is ascx.  Found in the 15 hive /TEMPLATE/CONTROLTEMPLATES, you'll need to have an on-prem installation to get to them.